# Oracle DDL triggers properties?

Tags: oracle, triggers, oracle11g, ddl

Which statement is true about triggers on data definition language (DDL) statements?

A. They can be used to track changes only to a table or Index.

B. They can be defined by all users in the database or only by a specific user.

C. They are fired only when the owner of the object Issues the DDL statement.

D. They can be used to track changes to a table, table space, view, or synonym.

Which is the most correct answer,A is surely wrong i am confused with B,C,D. I did a lot of research but not found anything relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer A is certainly wrong - DDL triggers can apply to more than just tables or indexes.

Answer B is not really clear: A trigger can be created by any user provided the required priviliges has been granted to this user. It is not limited to a certain user, e.g. `SYS`

Answer C is certainly wrong - it doesn't matter who issues the DDL statement.

**Answer D seems to be correct.** Almost all `CREATE`, `DROP`, `ALTER` statements are DDL statements, those may fire a DDL trigger.

Comment: Thanks Wernfried & Jeffrey,,,

Answer (score 1):

Answer B could be right if we suppose that "by" was mistakenly written instead of "for". Answer D though looks right but limits the set of object types. For example, changes to functions and procedures can also be tracked.